# Flutter compare two time string

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 String in which I have hours and min

```
String1  = 2 HOUR 0 MIN
String2  = 1 HOUR 30 MIN
```

I need to check if I subtract `String2` time with `String1` values to go to negative or not.

For example, if I subtract `String2` with `String1` value will be in a time like 00:30

So basically I just need to check `String2` is not greater then `String1`, I am badly stuck on this how can i check it

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're using Strings instead of [Durations](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration-class.html)? The duration class has built in methods to add and subtract hours, mins, etc.

If you have to use strings, I would first convert them to Durations and add/subtract them.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider first converting the `Strings` to `Duration` by parsing them. This can be done with a regexp for example:

```dart
/// Returns the duration associated with a string of
/// the form "XX HOUR XX MIN" where XX can be 1 or 2 digits
///
/// TODO: add check for fail safe
Duration _parseDateString(String dateString) {
  // Make sure that this is correct, it really depends on the form of your input string
  final dateStringRegexp = RegExp(r'(\d*) HOUR (\d*) MIN');

  final match = dateStringRegexp.firstMatch(dateString);
  final hours = int.parse(match!.group(1)!);
  final minutes = int.parse(match.group(2)!);

  return Duration(hours: hours, minutes: minutes);
}
```

Once you have this, it's pretty easy to compare the times:

```dart
final dateString1 = "2 HOUR 0 MIN";
final dateString2 = "1 HOUR 30 MIN ";

final duration1 = _parseDateString(dateString1);
final duration2 = _parseDateString(dateString2);

print(duration1.compareTo(duration2));
```